# leave gcloud project in terminal

Tags: zsh, gcloud

How can I leave my current gcloud project via the cloud cli so I can revert back to my normal terminal?

```
15:40:08 in ~ using ☁️  default/192085439987
```

I just want to be using

```
15:40:08 in ~
```

I have managed to swap between projects using

```
gcloud config set project <project id>
```

But can't seem to leave anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the `gcloud` command the terminal keeps the same properties, if any it could change the shell you're using, in that case to return back to your previous shell you can just type `exit` which normally would take you out of the last shell.

Here are some detailed instructions to go back the old shell or prompt depending on what changed on your side:

1. Determine the shell you're using before starting the `gcloud` command by typing `echo $SHELL`, this will provide the name of the shell which could be something like `/bin/bash` for bash or `/bin/zsh` for zshell.
2. Once that you have finished using `gcloud`, type `$SHELL` again and determine if the shell you're using now changed. If it did changed, normally with an `exit` command you would leave the old shell, if it doesn't work you can type the whole route of the binary and you will switch to it, for example type `/bin/zsh` to go back to `zsh`
3. If the [prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt) also changed, you can go back to the default one by executing `. ./.profile`, `source ~/.zshrc` for `zsh` or `source ~/.bashrc` for `bash`

If the prompt is changed since the beginning (before executing the `gcloud` command) then you probably have to edit your `.profile` or `.zshrc` files to set them as you like to have them, more information about it, can be found [here](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html)

Comment: I typed exit and still have `12:01:39 in ~ using ☁️  default/` is this always going to be here if I have the SDK installed on my machine?

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide more detailed instructions

Comment: Thanks man ill look into point 3.  much appericated

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what I am after

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/properties#unsetting_properties

```
gcloud config unset disable_usage_reporting
```

Can someone confirm?